# What kind of mathematical model is this?

Tags: dynamical-systems, delay-differential-equations

I am making a highly simplified economic model. When I started with it, I assumed it would become a model of ordinary delayed differential equations, but it turns out to be something different, which I don't know how to categorize or analyse. (In the end I'd like to know if there can be cycles or multiple equilibria in the model).

The model is as follows

> There are 2 sectors: the Electricity Sector, and the Coal Sector. They have a circular relation (coal is used to produce electricity, and electricity is used to produce coal).
>
> 1. Electricity production $e(t)$ has an **immediate effect** on coal production $c(t)$, but coal has to be transported to the electricity plant and has a **delay** $\Delta$.
> 2. Coal can be stored near the electric plant, and $s(t)$ is the amount stored at $t$, but electricity cannot be stored.
> 3. coal production has a maximum capacity of $\kappa$ coal per unit $t$, at which rate it consumes $\alpha$ units of electricity per unit $t$.
> 4. Coal is absorbed at rate $a(t)$, depending on coal available and electricity need, which produces $\beta$ electricity per unit coal. This means $\alpha/ \beta$ is the max needed coal absorption per $t$ to satisfy maximum coal production.

This gives the following relations:

> $c(t)=min(\kappa,\frac{\kappa}{\alpha}e(t))$
>
> $\dot s(t)=c(t-\Delta)-a(t)$
>
> $a(t)=\{\begin{matrix}\
> if \quad s(t)>0:min(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}, a^{max}) \qquad       \\ 
> if \quad s(t) = 0:min(\frac{\alpha}{\beta},c(t-\Delta))
> \end{matrix}$
>
> $e(t)=\beta \cdot a(t)$

**Now my question is as follows:**

The only differential equation here is the one about the change in stored coal over time $\dot s$. Yet, The variables I am primarily interested in are coal and electricity production $c(t), e(t)$.

I could simply substitute the electricity and coal functions into the $\dot s$ relation, and treat it as a delayed ordinary differential equation of one variable, but then I would only be analyzing fluctuations in stored coal, which (I think) doesn't allow me to analyse the change in electricity and coal production over time. But $c(t)$, and $e(t)$ are not in differential equation form.

**So how do I analyse $c(t)$ and $e(t)$ here** (find out whether there are cycles, multiple equilibria, or compute numerical examples, e.g. I'd like to compute examples in mathematica), **and more generally, what kind of category of dynamical system is this?**

**Edit:** I just realized that when I said "I could simply substitute the electricity and coal functions into the $\dot s$ relation", I was wrong, because it actually seems to be impossible to substitute $c$ and $e$ into $\dot s$, without getting into an infinite regress, where you have to refer to $c(t-\Delta), c(t-2\Delta), c(t-3\Delta), ...$. This makes my question even more pertinent.

Comment: Is the amount of coal transported in small amounts continuously, like oil through a pipe, or discretely like a singular truck carrying all the coal produced at the factory all at once to the electricity plant? In other words, does the electricity sector get the coal all at once or continuously?

Comment: continuous. in reality it would not be continuous, except by approximation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've written down a very interesting system, from the mathematical point of view! I would eliminate $e$ and write the system as
\begin{align}
 c(t) =& \kappa\min (1, \tfrac{\beta}{\alpha} a(t)), \tag{1a}\\
 a(t) =& \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl} \min(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}, a^\text{max}) & \text{if} & s(t) > 0,\\ \min(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}, c(t-\Delta)) & \text{if} & s(t) = 0 \end{array}\right. ,\tag{1b}\\
 \frac{\text{d} s}{\text{d} t} =& c(t-\Delta) - a(t).\tag{1c}
\end{align}
I would call this a delay-differential-algebraic piecewise smooth system, if that helps at all. As you've found out, you cannot reduce it to delay-differential equation for $s$, because you would have to have knowledge of $c$ at every previous time $t-n \Delta$.

The analysis of the existence of equilibria is the easiest, so let's start with that. Assume there exist $(c_*,a_*,s_*)$ that solve our system and are time-independent. The ODE for $s$, equation (1c), then implies that
\begin{equation}
c_* = a_*.
\end{equation}
From equation (1a) it follows that either $c_* = \kappa$ or $\kappa \frac{\beta}{\alpha} = 1$, which is a condition on the parameters. Assuming the most general situation, i.e. where the system parameters are chosen freely, we focus on the case $c_* = \kappa = a_*$. Note that this implies that $\frac{\beta}{\alpha} a_* = \frac{\beta}{\alpha} \kappa > 1$. We can now use equation (1b) to see if multiple choices for $s_*$ are possible.

Suppose $s_* = 0$. Then, (1b) is satisfied if $c_* = \kappa > \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ or $\kappa = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$, which is the same parameter condition we encountered in the analysis of equation (1a). So, without assuming any such relation on parameters, we obtain

> *Result 1:* If the model parameters satisfy the inequality $\kappa > \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$, then $(c,a,s) = (\kappa,\kappa,0)$ is an equilibrium of the system.

Now suppose $s_* > 0$. Then, (1b) is satisfied if $\kappa = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ or $\kappa = a^\text{max}$. Both are conditions on parameters, which are not satisfied in general if you're allowed to choose your system parameters freely. Therefore, we can state

> *Result 2:* If and only if $a^\text{max} = \kappa$, then $(c,a,s) = (\kappa,\kappa,s_*)$ is an equilibrium of the system, for any choice of $s_*>0$.

What about this special case $\kappa = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$? Let's look at equation (1a) first. Assume that $\frac{\beta}{\alpha} a_* > 1$, then $c_* = \kappa$. But that implies that $a_* = \kappa = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$, which violates our assumption. Assuming that $\frac{\beta}{\alpha} a_* < 1$ leads to a contradiction in the same way, and therefore we again get $c_* = \kappa = a_*$. Equation (1b) is again satisfied if we choose $s_* = 0$. However, we cal *also* satisfy equation (1b) for $s_* > 0$ if we choose $a^\text{max} < \frac{\alpha}{\beta} = \kappa$. This leads to

> *Result 3:* Suppose that $\kappa = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$. If $a^\text{max} < \kappa$, then $(c,a,s) = (\kappa,\kappa,s_*)$ is an equilibrium of the system, for any choice of $s_*>0$.

**To conclude:** For a region in parameter space (where $\kappa > \frac{\alpha}{\beta}$) there exists a unique equilibrium solution for the system. I hope that's in any way helpful.

**By the way**, you can reduce system (1) to an integro-delay equation for $a$. Writing
\begin{align}
 s(t) =& s(0) + \int_0^t c(\tau-\Delta)-a(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau\\
 =& s(0) + \int_0^t \kappa \,\min(1,\tfrac{\beta}{\alpha}a(\tau-\Delta))-a(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau,
\end{align}
you end up with the equation
\begin{equation}
a(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl} \min(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}, a^\text{max}) & \text{if} & s(0) + \int_0^t \kappa \,\min(1,\tfrac{\beta}{\alpha}a(\tau-\Delta))-a(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau > 0,\\ \min(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}, \kappa \,\min(1,\tfrac{\beta}{\alpha}a(t-\Delta))) & \text{if} & s(0) + \int_0^t \kappa \,\min(1,\tfrac{\beta}{\alpha}a(\tau-\Delta))-a(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau = 0 \end{array}\right. .
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to analyse it first before responding, hence the delay. Firstly, I'm somewhat confused by your approach for the equilibria, since it seems to only use $\dot s=0$. It seems to me that we can't simply state $\dot a=0, \dot c=0$, since they are delayed equations, so if $\dot a=0$ at some $t$, then $a$ could still change at a later $t$, since the initial condition is a function, instead of a constant. e.g., if the initial condition is $[c(t)=1$ on $[-\Delta,-\frac{1}{2}\Delta], c(t)=-t$ on $[-\frac{1}{2} \Delta,0]$, then $\dot a=0$ will hold on $[0,1/2\Delta]$, but not after that

Comment: Secondly, how do we analyse the stability of equilibria in such systems? I did some examples, and it seems to me that $(c,a,s)=(0,0,0)$ (which is also an equilibrium I think you've intentionally ignored) is an unstable equilibrium if $\kappa \frac{\beta}{\alpha}>1$, and a stable one if $\kappa \frac{\beta}{\alpha}<1$, but I'm not 100% sure. It seems from numerical examples that if $\kappa \frac{\beta}{\alpha}>1$, then an initial condition that is slightly above $0$ (meaning the average of $c(t)$ on $[-\Delta,0]$ is slightly above $0$), will automatically move to the point where

Comment: to the point where $a(t)=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$, and $c(t)=\kappa$, and where $s(t)$ is increasing at a constant rate of $\kappa-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$. However, How do we investigate this rigorously in a system like this?

Comment: To respond to your comments:
*1)* I consider an 'equilibrium' of the system to be a state that does not change in time, i.e. where all model components $(c,a,s)$ are constant in time, for all time. Moreover, and that's I think more appropriate to the point you're making, I assume that $(c,a,s)$ are **continuous**, so if they are constant, they have **the same value** for all time. Implicitly, I exclude so-called piecewise constant solutions, which might discontinuously jump from one value to another at some moment. Be that as it may, I believe the assumption of continuity is reasonable (?)

Comment: *2)* I indeed should have been more clear on why I ignored the trivial equilibrium $(0,0,0)$ -- which maybe isn't very trivial after all. I just assumed that, given the application, the situation where at least something happens would be more interesting than the situation where all model components are identically zero. However, from a perturbative/stability point of view, the trivial steady state is of course very relevant. Its stability is somewhat nontrivial, because if we assume that *all three* components $(c,a,s)$ are perturbed by a small positive amount, then ...

Comment: ... the $a$-equation leads to a contradiction, since $\min (\frac{\alpha}{\beta}, a^\text{max})$ is not arbitrarily small. It is possible to perturb the trivial equilibrium only in the $(c,a)$-variables though. For small $(c,a)$, we obtain $c(t) =\kappa \frac{\beta}{\alpha} c(t-\Delta)$, which can be solved to obtain $c(t) = c_0 \left(\kappa\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)^{-1+\frac{t}{\Delta}}$, confirming your observation that the stability is determined by the sign of $\kappa \frac{\beta}{\alpha} -1$.

Comment: Lastly, I have to emphasise that I'm not well versed in delay equations at all, apart from having some general knowledge about them. I'm sure there are other people who can say more sensible things about the stability analysis than I can. I added a few tags to your question to draw their attention.